# WPF/C# TabItem Header in horizontal accordion style. Possible?

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol, tabitem

I have a **TabControl** and there I want to change the header style.
I work with **C#** and **WPF**.

The **TabItem header** need to be in horizontal accordion style.
I hope you know what I mean. If you didn't then I can show your picture.
Is it possible to achieve my project? Without additional plug-in.

My own search skills are not enough to get the answer.
What I found is **DevExpress**...with this its possible.
But when I want to use this I need a license and so on.
I want to avoid it.

Hope for help. For more information(Code, Picture and so on) ask me.

Kind Regards

Comment: Please precise your question with code or picture. What have done so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean something like this, right?
[image]

It is possible, as seen in [this article](https://diptimayapatra.wordpress.com/2010/03/05/accordion-in-wpf-toolkit/).
I'm pretty sure you will have to implement your own **UserControl** in order to create an accordion-style **TabControl**.

Comment: That is what I mean. But for that I need Expression Blend, or?

Comment: Ordinarily you wouldn't implement your own usercontrol. You need to modify the template of the existing WPF TabControl. You can still make use of all its existing properties and behavior, but you change the visual presentation. In the XAML Designer, right-click on the tab control and select Edit Template | Edit a Copy... from the context menu. It's a big hassle  -- but if there's existing code that suits your needs where somebody did it with a new UserControl, by all means use that.

Comment: Thanks, I play a little bit around with the new stuff. I report tomorrow how it's going.

Comment: i don't think this is horizontal accordion.
isn't this is a vertical one?